# Integrating SwiftyJSON into project

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to integrate SwiftyJSON into my project from here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. I am currently using a workspace file, and I am having issues importing the SwiftyJSON files into my project.

On the GitHub page, it says that if you're using a .xcworkspace file, you should drag the .xcodeproj into your project. However, when I do that and I set the correct target there are several errors and it does not seem right. It also does not let me import SwiftyJSON in my project either.

I attempted to use Cocoapods, and I got this

[image]

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use CocoaPods!!!, it's more easy to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the pod in ur podfile and you should be fine, it'd avoid all that nonsense of dragging in projects, and do `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

Firt of all run in your command line `sudo gem install cocoapods` to get the last version of Cocoapods. As in the error indicate  you need to use the [`use_frameworks!`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#use_frameworks_bang), see the sample `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks! 

platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I did this, and it did not work. Is it potentially because i am using Xcode 7 and testing in iOS 9?

Comment: Share the content of your Podfile please

Comment: @Varun try it without the `platform :ios, '8.0'` it's technically not needed.